# Getting contacts freezes the app

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, contacts, intentservice

I have an app that gets a list of contacts from the device. This works perfectly as expected every time, unless if called from a BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receiver. When called from the app itself, the list of contacts is returned, but when called from this broadcast receiver upon device boot, it will try to get the contacts but freezes, and if I have it print log statements they show that it goes through the list of contacts but then at some point eventually freezes.

My BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receiver sets an immediate alarm like so:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //set time to now to trigger now
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        long notificationTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, EndBlurAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, notificationTime, pendingIntent);
```

The alarm receiver then calls an async task by calling new `GetNewContactsTask(this).execute();` and then the asynctask GetNewContactsTask is set up like this:

```
@Override
    protected List<Contact> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if(context != null){
            return PhoneDataRetriever.getInstance(context).getContacts();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Contact> resultList){
        PrefManager.setup(context);
        MyLog.i("Returned contact list of size " + resultList.size() + ". Saving...");
    }
```

But the onPostExecute of that task is never called, it hangs up in the doInBackground() method. the getContacts() method of PhoneDataRetriever that gets the contacts is set up like this:

```
public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        MyLog.i("Getting contacts...");
        List<Contact> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    //FREEZES HERE
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        Contact contact = new Contact(name, returnOnlyNumbers(phoneNo));
                        returnList.add(contact);
                        //MyLog.i(contact);
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

That is the method that usually works, but when called from this boot receiver it will freeze where I commented. It will go through the loop many times but eventually will freeze at that spot (I previously had Log statements all throughout this method to figure out what's going on).

What is it about the broadcast receiver that makes it freeze when trying to get the contacts?

Comment: Did you set permissions in Manifest?

Comment: Yes, which is why getting the contacts usually works I am not sure why it isn't now.